# Calculate amount of combinations with conditions

Tags: vba, math, stochastic

I'd like to calculate how many different variations of a certain amount of numbers are possible. The number of elements is variable.

Example:
I have 5 elements and each element can vary between 0 and 8. Only the first element is a bit more defined and can only vary between 1 and 8. So far I'd say I have 8*9^4 possibilities. But I have some more conditions. As soon as one of the elements gets zero the next elements should be automatically zero as well.

E.G:

6 5 4 7 8 is ok

6 3 6 8 0 is ok

3 6 7 0 5 is not possible and would turn to 3 6 7 0 0

Would somebody show me how to calculate the amount of combinations for this case and also in general, because I'd like to be able to calculate it also for 4 or 8 or 9 etc. elements. Later on I'd like to calculate this number in VBA to be able give the user a forecast how long my calculations will take.

Comment: This is a pure mathematical question, not a programmatical one! And you also know how to distinguish the first value; how would you go for the next ones?

Comment: Yes but that's valid for any positions except the first one. That means 3 0 6 5 4 is also not valid. I thought the first element is not important for the caluclation because it anyway can't be zero. So if I do 8*9^4 - 9^3 -9^2 -9 i should have the possibilities. But that seems to be far too much. I coded the case with 5 elements in VBA and implemented a counter and I get 37448.

Comment: Are you saying you already have a VBA program to calculate the number, or do you want help in making such a program? Or are you saying you can now do it brute-force in VBA and you want a more efficient routine? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Rory, I have a VBA program to calculate values with the numbers mentioned above. But I can only do brute force in VBA and I would like to have a more efficient way. At the moment with 5 elements I have about 37448 iterations which takes with my laptop 0.4s. When I increase the number to 8 elements it takes already almost 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Since once a 0 is present in the sequence, all remaining numbers in the sequence will also be 0, these are all of the possibilities: (where `#` below represents any digit from `1` to `8`):

```
##### (accounts for 8^5 combinations)
####0 (accounts for 8^4 combinations)
...
#0000 (accounts for 8^1 combinations)
```

Therefore, the answer is (in pseudocode):

```
int sum = 0;

for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
{
   sum = sum + 8^x;
}
```

Or equivalently,

```
int prod = 0;

for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
{
   prod = 8*(prod+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

great thank you.

```
Sub test()
Dim sum As Single

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 6
    sum = sum + 8 ^ x
Next
Debug.Print sum
End Sub
```

With this code I get exactly 37488. I tried also with e.g. 6 elements and it worked as well. Now I can try to estimate the calculation time

Comment: I agree with @Imaginary, except to say that self-answers are welcome, as long as that they are an final solution and not an intermediate progress report.